# Download parser jars

Tags: python, bash, parsing, terminal, installation

I've been trying to install ddlite from https://github.com/HazyResearch/ddlite, but when the site directs me to download parser jars, I enter the code specified on the website

```
./install-parser.sh
```

but when I do that, I get the error

```
-bash: ./install-parser.sh: Permission denied.
```

Is there any workaround to this, or am I fundamentally misunderstanding what this website is asking? I'm relatively new to terminal.

Comment: Open an issue. https://github.com/HazyResearch/ddlite/issues

Comment: Is `install-parser.sh` executable? Did you `chmod +x install-parser.sh` before executing it?